# Template for child pages / subpages

Tags: pages, templates

I'm trying to build a template file for my custom post type that is different for the parent, child, and child's child post.

The best I've been able to find is the following code:

```
if( $post->post_parent !== 0 ) {
    get_template_part('content', 'child');
} else {
    get_template_part('content');
}
```

Only issue with this is that it only works for Parent > Child.

Is there any way to make this work for Parent > Child > Child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic idea:

Any page where the page parent ([`$post->post_parent`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)) is `0`, it means the page is a top level page. If any other value exists, the page is a child of another page. This value is the ID of the page that the specific page is a child to.

With the above information, we can calculate if the page is a child or a granchild using `get_post` and the returned `WP_Post` properties.

You can try the following: (*CAVEAT: Untested*)

```
if ($post->post_parent === 0) {

    //Do something for post parent

} else {

    $q = get_post($post->post_parent);

    if ($q->post_parent === 0) {

        //Do something for direct child

    } else {

        // Do something for grand child

    }

}
```

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Comment: Apologies for the belated reply. Works like a charm!